# Javascript- Console.log between multiple prompts

Tags: javascript, command-prompt, console.log

Im pretty sure that a lot of people have encountered this situation.  For Ex: You have a simple Choose Your Own Adventure game from JS.

```js
    var name = prompt("Name?");
    console.log("Hello" + name);
    var age = prompt("Age?");
    console.log(name + " is " + age + " years old");
```

what happens is the first prompt is shown and then the second prompt (age) is shown immediately afterwards.  Also, the console doesn't even print out the "Hello" + (name) until after you answer the two prompts.  Is there anyway you can "force-print" the console.log between the two prompts?

Comment: Just tried this in chrome and its working as expected...

Comment: In my version of Chrome (59.0.3071.) it doesn't. In fact, this is a well-known issue with browser generated dialogs.

Comment: If you are working with `prompt()`, you might as well use `alert()` for your outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the UI is being updated faster than the JavaScript is executing and this is causing a problem syncing with the `console.log` statements.

This happens because the JavaScript runtime is not responsible for updating the UI, that's the browsers job and so once the JavaScript asks the browser to update the UI (display the prompt), it does it very quickly and since a `propmt` is a "blocking" dialog, all other code is suspended.

Adding a short delay solves the problem:

```js
var name = prompt("Name?");
console.log("Hello " + name);

// Force a 10 millisecond delay before running the rest of the code.
setTimeout(function(){
  var age = prompt("Age?");
  console.log(name + " is " + age + " years old");
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Generator functions which are part of the ES6

```
function * quiz() {
  var name = prompt("Name?");
  yield console.log("Hello" + name);
  var age = prompt("Age?");
  yield console.log(name + " is " + age + " years old");
}

var myQuiz = quiz();
myQuiz.next();
myQuiz.next();
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6mzbhLhz/ - see It in console.

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as the original code.