# How can I display a Javascript output in real time?

Tags: javascript

Apologies if this is a simple question, but is there a way to output Javascript to the console in real-time, while pausing at each user interaction. In other words, if I did something as simple as...

```js
console.log("What's your name: ");
let userName = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log(userName);

console.log("\n");

console.log("Nice to meet you " + userName + "! What is your age?");
let userAge = prompt("What is your age?");
console.log(userAge);
```

...can I get the name outputted to the screen before the age prompt comes up? This is doable in other teaching environments (MS Basic & the command prompt), but either doesn't exist in Javascript, or I'm missing something.

Thanks for helping the newb!

Comment: The name would show up when you say `console.log(userName)`. Do you want it to write to the document?

Comment: This is indeed possible -- you need to make use of a `Promise()`. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44790006/javascript-console-log-between-multiple-prompts).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to load HTML before Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953572/unable-to-load-html-before-javascript)

Comment: What's the issue ? This code works just fine.

Comment: Aniket G - it does show up, but instantly. The entirety of the code shows instantly. I would like it to execute step-by-step, with the next prompt only appearing after the results of the first appear on screen.

Comment: Obsidian - I'll take a look at that - thanks!

Comment: @ObsidianAge - I read through the other question, and attempted to integrate it into my code. It doesn't seem to have the intended effect. Also using a Promise() is a little ahead of me for the time being. Is there an easier fashion, or is this simply not something that is a native function (I don't mean function in the programming sense) of JS & the console?

Comment: Just replace your `console.log` statements with `document.write` - it will overwrite the entire contents of the page as you go.

Comment: @tymeJV - it does not appear to. I made the changes, and still got the two pop-up windows asking for the name & age, and then the web page displayed all the content. Nothing is displayed before all the Javascript completes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of setTimeout, something like this:

```
console.log("What's your name: ");
let userName = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log(userName);

console.log("\n");
setTimeout(function(){
console.log("Nice to meet you " + userName + "! What is your age?");
let userAge = prompt("What is your age?");
console.log(userAge);
},1000)
```

Note: This is one way to do it there are ample of other ways to do it.

In case if you want to use promises:

```
let userName,userAge, userSport;
function basic(){
console.log("What's your name: ");
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
userName = prompt("What is your name?");
resolve(userName)
})
promise1.then(function(value){
console.log(value);
console.log("\n");
console.log("Nice to meet you " + value + "! What is your age?");
var promise2 =  new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
userAge = prompt("What is your age?");
resolve(userAge)
})
promise2.then(function(value){
console.log(value)
console.log("Nice to meet you " + userName + " aged: " +userAge + ". Let us know your favorite sports")

var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
userSport = prompt("What is your favorite sports?");
resolve(userSport)
})
promise3.then(function(value){
console.log(value)
console.log("Nice to meet you " + userName + " aged:  " +userAge + " and your favorite sports is " +value)
console.log("\n");
console.log("Thanks");
})
})
})

}
basic()
```

Comment: Thanks @Adarsh - quick follow-up question - if I ask a third question (say, favorite sport) and use that setTimeout function again, it has no effect. The one above works, but another one immediately after does not delay the third question. I've checked other answers on here that appear to use setTimeout repeatedly, so I'm not sure why mine does not function as intended. Thanks!

Comment: You need to increase the delay for the latter one.. if you keep the delay to 1000 ms for both then it will trigger both one after other because it would have waited for 1000 ms for both. Try to increase the latter one to 2000 ms .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `async/await` functionality and promises. I personally do not always like to use `.then` so this is my version of using Promises.

```js
const Q1 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  let userName = prompt('What is your name?');
  console.log(`What is your name: ${userName}`);
  resolve(userName);
})

const Q2 = (userName) => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(`Nice to meet you ${userName}! What is your age?`);
  let age = prompt('What is your age?');
  console.log(age);
  resolve(age);
})

 const userPrompt = async () => {
   let name = await Q1();
   let age = await Q2(name); // assigned to variable should you want to use it in next question
 }
 
 userPrompt();
```

You can now just add additional questions as functions.

Also here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geqm4hvu/). If you run it and open the console you will see that the name is displayed before the age prompt is opened.

Comment: @FZs True it is not async but it forces the code to wait until prompt has finished before it continues to the `console.log` statement. If you run the initial snippet from OP you will see that the `console.log` statement prints `null`. I agree that it is not the conventional way of using `async/await`, however, I see no reason why you could not use this to force async functions to wait for "long running" functions. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The OP's snippet works (It shows `null` if you click 'cancel'). But the original question was -if I understood correctly- to -for example- see *What's your name:* in the console **before** the first prompt comes up, what your answer -in its current form- didn't accomplish too. And about `await` (from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#Description)): ***If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise,*** -and it isn't- ***it's converted to a resolved Promise***: so the code proceeds immediately. Happy coding!

Comment: @FZs thanks for the clarification, it appears my understanding of `await` was therefore incorrect. Much appreciated

Comment: @NeillHerbst - just to clarify - it was intended to mean that the user would receive a prompt ('what's your name: '), would answer, and then 'what's your name: Jon' would appear on screen just before the second prompt appears. Also, I don't know if it's my browser, but when I check the code snippet at JSFiddle, nothing appears in the output frame. Yours isn't the only one - I've had this problem with a few - not sure why - I'm using an up-to-date Chrome.

Comment: And thanks to all for the help - appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @MDG If I'm not mistaken the output on JSFiddle is HTML so you would not see any console output. You must open the developer tools `F12` in Chrome to see the console.

Comment: I updated my answer to show the correct usage with `async/await`. Again thanks @FZs for the correction.